# Jenkins+SVN: svn: E175002: OPTIONS

Tags: svn, jenkins, collabnet

I am unable to run build with Jenkins and at the console I could find below error. But I have verified repository root directory and as well as sub directorie's access via browser and it is fine.

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in workspace /path/project
Updating http://<IP>/path/to/repo at revision  
U         rpms/src/main/
At revision 6374
hudson.util.IOException2: revision check failed on http://<IP>/path/to/repo/subfolders
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:178)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.run(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:113)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:649)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:810)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1382)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1593)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /path/to/repo/subfolders failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:379)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:364)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:708)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:628)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:103)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1018)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:180)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:118)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:148)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:45)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteLog.run(SvnRemoteLog.java:160)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteLog.run(SvnRemoteLog.java:35)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:967)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:872)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:166)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS path/to/repo/subfolders failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: OPTIONS request failed on '/path/to/repo/subfolders'
svn: E170001: OPTIONS of '/path/to/repo/subfolders': 403 Forbidden (http://<IP>/)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:62)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:748)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: svn: E170001: OPTIONS of '/path/to/repo/subfolders': 403 Forbidden (http://<IP>/)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:189)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:141)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.createDefaultErrorMessage(HTTPRequest.java:452)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:189)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:460)
    ... 30 more
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

We are using CollabSVN in a CentOS6 OS.

Please help.

Comment: One doubt, I have seen `.subversion/auth` folder but I coulndt see any data in it. So I have not removed .subversion folder and multiple projects are there in Jenkins. If in case I have to remove .subversion directory will it cause any trouble to other projects ?

Comment: are you allowed (authorization-wise) to hit that remote repo? in your stack, i see a 403 (FORBIDDEN):
`Caused by: svn: E170001: OPTIONS of '/path/to/repo/subfolders': 403 Forbidden (http://<IP>/)`  is <IP> your redaction of your IP address or did you forget to configure your remote repo's IP?

Comment: @matiaselgart ,Hi. Yes even I did a checkout in a temp directory from the remote machine and I havent faced any issues.<IP> is like I edited that part to replace my original IP.

Comment: hmm. two other possible probs. (1) when you run it locally (outside of Jenkins) and it works -- is Jenkins using the same SVN that you were using locally? (2) when you run it locally, do you have any configuration in your local environment that you do not have in Jenkins? SSH keys or something? how are you authenticating into SVN repo from jenkins vs your local env where it works?

Comment: Yes we are using same username and password for Jenkins as well. 2) No SSH keys as authentication via HTTP(apache) protocol. 3) at Jenkins we have a SVN plugin installed and there we enter our credentials to access.

Comment: Ok in that case I will review Jenkins SVN conf once, Thank you @matiaselgart. aah! its actually CollabSVN and logs were not enabled. I found few blog posts about enabling logs. I will try them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the stacktrace definitely shows an authentication exception, so i would suspect your SVN configuration on Jenkins not being correct:

```
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: (...)
```

If you control the remote repo (your server?) perhaps you can enable verbose logging on that side to see what's going on? or at least look at logs.

Answer (score -3):

This problem happens when Jenkins is not able to connect with your SVN repository.
Some possible reasons for this to happen are that:

1. Your credentials to connect to the repository are not valid.
2. The Repository branch path is not valid.
3. The SVN server is down.